# Doing code coverage for XSLT template (NUnit)

Tags: xslt, code-coverage, opencover

Currently i am using Nunit, and use OpenCover to do code coverage for all my csharp (.cs) file.
But some of the Nunit Test Case contains XSLT transformation in .xslt template.
Any expert here know if there is any way I can do code coverage for XSLT template?

I needed this so I can know which line of XSLT code being covered, and create more test cases to cover other area which has not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSpec unit testing framework for XSLT includes code coverage analysis: see https://github.com/xspec/xspec/wiki/Code-Coverage

I haven't used it myself.